# Experiencing weird issue while making FTP connection using hxtt diver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ftp, hxtt

I am trying to access one file via FTP using hxtt driver, but I am able to make a connection. If I pass username and password in URL it is successful, but I get an exception if I pass username and password separately in properties file. Please see details below:

Jars I have tried with:

- Text_JDBC40.jar latest jar
- Text_JDBC41.jar latest jar
- Text_JDBC42.jar
  latest jar

Works fine:

```
Class.forName("com.hxtt.sql.text.TextDriver").newInstance();
String url = "jdbc:csv:/ftp://<username>:<password>@www.hxtt.net/testdemo/sample?_CSV_Separator=,";

String sql = "select * from Test"; 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Throws an exception:

```
Class.forName("com.hxtt.sql.text.TextDriver").newInstance();
String url = "jdbc:csv:/ftp://www.hxtt.net/testdemo/sample?_CSV_Separator=,";
Properties prperties = new Properties();
prperties.put("user", "<username>");
prperties.put("password", "<password>");
String sql = "select * from Test";
```

Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to login ftp server www.hxtt.net:21
    at com.caigen.global.ao.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.aL(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.bm.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.az.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.a9.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.av.iL(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.i.iN(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.b7.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.text.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.text.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.global.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.HxttDriver.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.HxttDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.test.HXTTConnectionTest4.main(HXTTConnectionTest4.java:35)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to login ftp server www.hxtt.net:21
    at com.caigen.global.ao.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.aL(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.bm.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.az.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.a9.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.ak.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.av.iL(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.concurrent.i.iN(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.b7.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.text.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.text.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.global.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.HxttDriver.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.HxttDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.test.HXTTConnectionTest4.main(HXTTConnectionTest4.java:35)
```

Comment: Apparently this driver doesn't support user and password through a `Properties` object. You will need to pass it through the URL, and maybe report a bug or improvement request with hxtt (JDBC drivers should support this with `Properties`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : thanks. but hxtt already confirmed that they have added support for this approach.

It says java.sql.SQLException: Failed to login ftp server www.hxtt.net:21

it means something is related connection but then how it is working for URL approach ?

Comment: The error suggests they don't support it. If hxtt says they added support, you should ask them why your code is failing, or you should check if you're using the right version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: you were very right about this. thanks Mark.